# I cannot run the Knit (Knit to HTML) of an RMarkdown

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr

I get this error when I run the Knit to HTML of an RMarkdown

"Error in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")) :    number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2) Calls: :: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne ->  Execution halted"

When I run the RMarkdown chunck by chunck it works, but when I run the Knit no. Do you know how can you help me ?

Comment: Interesting problem.  When you knit R runs the code in its own session.  I am guessing that it is not finding a data object.  If you are in R Studio reset your session (session menu > Restart R) and see if the code continues to work if you run it line by line.  Hopefully that will give you a clue as to where the problem is happening.  Does it give you the line number of a particular chunk?  If so, can you share that?

Comment: Also make sure all your libraries you need are all in one of the first R chunks to make sure the libraries are loaded, as well as restart your R session mentioned above. Also copying the code and creating a new projects then paste the code might solve this intermittent issue

Comment: I tried restarting R and Knit the RMarkdown after loading all packages. It works if I run the file chunk by chunk but it still doesn't work if I run the knit.